# Add SSH key for both github and bitbucket in single PC

Tags: github, bitbucket

Is it possible to use both the  github and bitbucket repo in personal computer.

if not, Let me know any other possibilities.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

**Complete Guide to Add SSH keys for both github and bitbucket in single PC**

if you already have one ssh key then you must have 2 files public(id_rsa.pub) and Private key(id_rsa) in the .ssh folder You can Skip the **Step 2**

**Step 1. Prepare your default identity it Required for Both Account Before Doing Step 2 and Step 3**

Determine your Git clone URL.
$ git remote -v

```
origin git@bitbucket.org:teamsinspace/bitbucketspacestation.git (fetch)
origin git@bitbucket.org:teamsinspace/bitbucketspacestation.git (push)
```

Update the remote URL with your Bitbucket username by replacing git@bitbucket.org with `<username>@bitbucket.org`.
For this step and the ones that follow, enter your username in place of .

$ git remote set-url origin `<username>@bitbucket.org:teamsinspace/bitbucketspacestation.git`

**Step 2 : create the 1st ssh key with default names (id_rsa)**

$`ssh-keygen`

You will see the following text:

```
Generating public/private RSA key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

you can input the password to secure your file or you can press enter for all the steps and then it will create one ssh key.

[image: After you keep pressing enter]

By default, the system adds keys for all identities to the `/Users/<username>/.ssh` directory

**You can check the already existing ssh key by following command**

$ `ls ~/.ssh`

```
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub
```

Two files should be there one with the name of the key(id_rsa) Private key second with the same (ir_rsa.pub)  public key.

you can open make it visible by `ctrl + h`  in Home Directory
then it will be shown

[image]

Second, Create your known hosts file if you not have already

To create your known hosts files-
`touch known_hosts`

**STEP 3 :  Sethup the Multiple account ssh**

**3.1 : Create 2nd Key With default name**

You might be using one SSH key pair for working on your company's internal projects, now but you might be need a diffrent key for accessing a client's servers so you can create the key

By run the same command `ssh-keygen` again it will create the 2nd ssh key files with the name of  `[ id_rsa2  and id_rsa2.pub ]`

**3.2 : Create the 2nd Key with Custom Name**

`ssh-keygen -f NAME_OF_YOUR_KEY`

$ `ssh-keygen -f work_key` it will create  then 2 files
`[ work_key, work_key.pub ]`

if want to run the one key at a time then you can use this command before connecting to that repo for pull and push .

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/YOUR_KEY_FILE
```

`ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/work_key`

**Step 4 : Setup both two Accounts at the same time**

You want to Setup both two Accounts at the same time then you will have to use the following command

Third Create your config file
To create your config file
`touch config` or open directly into any text editor,

Here is Example for One Github and one Bitbucket account

Host : name of your ssh setting you can give custom name
HostName : github domain or bitbucket domain
IdentityFile : path of your ssh file

```
#Work account 
Host pers 
    HostName github.com 
    User git 
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
    UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts 
    IdentitiesOnly yes

#Personal account 
Host work 
    HostName bitbucket.org 
    User git 
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_key 
    UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts 
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

**Step 5 : Add your public keys to the Bitbucket or github account**
For Bitbucket
[image]
For Github [Go to Setting of your Account -> SSH and GPG key]
[image]

**Step 6 : Add your public permanently**

ssh HOST(What we written in config file )
like
`ssh work`

if you got this error make sure you did Step 4 Correctly.

```
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
```

or can be use this way as well

Now you can use

```
git clone `git@pers/project.git`
```

```
git clone `git@work/project.git`
```

[image]

**Step 7 : auotmaticly pick by domain name we are requiesting to**

Managing SSH keys can become cumbersome as soon as you need to use a second key. Traditionally, you would use ssh-add to store your keys to ssh-agent, typing in the password for each key. The problem is that you would need to do this every time you restart your computer, which can quickly become tedious.

if you have only two account and one in the github and one in the bitbucket you can use the following approch to auotmaticly pick by domain name we are requiesting to

```
#Work account 
Host github.com  
    HostName github.com 
    User git 
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
    UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts 
    IdentitiesOnly yes

#Personal account 
Host bitbucket.org 
    HostName bitbucket.org 
    User git 
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_key 
    UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts 
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Here is a link to further guidance on it

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-ssh-setting-up-ssh-keys/
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-additional-ssh-keys/

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is. You tell git where the remote code lives from a per-repository configuration file. You can even push to GitHub and Bitbucket from the same repository if you want to.

See here for more details:
http://blog.lckymn.com/2013/03/11/git-push-to-pull-from-both-github-and-bitbucket/

One important piece will be connecting to each separately with SSH.

Your SSH keys should live in `$HOME/.ssh` and can contain any number of keys. The default name for an SSH key is `id_rsa` (or similar, depending on the protocol used to create it).

Try doing:

```
ls $HOME/.ssh
```

... to see what's in there.

I do what you are asking about myself and for me that brings up something like:

```
github-personal
github-personal.pub
bitbucket-work
bitbucket-work.pub
known_hosts
```

Where `known_hosts` is a file that contains a list of the servers I connect to and the public keys associated with them. The other files that end in `.pub` are my own public keys and the rest are my private keys.

You get your GitHub and Bitbucket keys into there by following their appropriate tutorials:

- GitHub: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/
- Bitbucket: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

Comment: Actually I have two user account namely xxx@gmail.com(github) and yyy@gmail.com(bitbucket). I would like to use both the accounts. So, how to do that?

Comment: @kabeerrifaye You can use both of the accounts. Do you want to have two separate repositories, one for each account? Or do you want one single repository to go to both Bitbucket and GitHub?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to use both the github and bitbucket repo in personal computer.

You can setup multiple SSH profiles.

- First Generate your SSH keys To generate the first key-from your root folder

  $ `cd ~/.ssh`
  $ `ssh-keygen -f work_key`,
  then enter a passphrase of your choice.
  To generate the second key
  $ `ssh-keygen -f personal_key`, then enter a passphrase of your choice.
- Second, Create your known hosts file
  To create your known hosts files-
  `touch known_hosts`
- Third Create your config file
  To create your config file
  `touch config`, then it would look something like this

  ```
  #Work account
  Host bitbucket.org
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  ```

  ```
  #Personal account
  Host bitbucket.org
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
  UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  ```
- Then add your SSH key to bitbucket. Go to bitbucket, settings, then SSH keys
  `pbcopy < id_rsa.pub` (to copy the key) and paste it in bitbucket

Comment: (Formatting/text decoration around *SSH keys `pbcopy < id_rsa.pub`* (still) looks off.)

Answer (score 0):

**Definitely YES.** You can generate ssh key pair first, see [How to generate](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/), then go to `.ssh` directory, copy the content of id_rsa.pub, and paste into your github or bitbucket ssh setting area.

Comment: Actually I have two user account namely xxx@gmail.com(github) and yyy@gmail.com(bitbucket). I would like to use both the accounts. How to do?

Answer (score 0):

I make use of Sourcefree Desktop Application and My Gitbash prompt
to push my project to Bitbucket and Github repository simultaneously
below is what i did

right click to open bash shell of the folder you want to push
First you need to create key, i will advice make use of the same ssh key

create key
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"

go to the folder directory
right click and click on git bash
then run the below command one after the other
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first"

open your sourcefree desktop app
click on + to open your local
repo file
create repo on bitbucket
then click repo icon
then click on repo icon to add
name: originbit
url: "repo link you created"

For your bitbucket you have to make use of both 
public ssh key and private ssh key if you want to make use of
both public and private repository

To make use of  ssh key earlier created
go to TOOLS icon of sourcefree App
Click on load tab
then resave it with .ppk extension
save the same key as private key and public key
in the same directory
dont input passhrase yet to avoid difficulties
just save it.

so that it can be loaded to pageant icon

to create new key 
go to TOOLS icon of sourcefree
then click on create ssh key
change the bottom number to 2048
but if you are unable to change it
first create a new key then drag your mouse around the colum provided
in a zigzag way or any form once created.
change the 1048 to 2048 so that it can be accepted at bitbucket ssh
then recreate a new key
then save it as public key and private key

add key to the Pageant (check your desktop notification for this Pageant key icon)
add both private ssh key and ssh public key

Goto your bitbucket account seetings 
and add the content of the two ssh keys
name them differently

go back to the bash shell

git status
git add -A
git pull originbit master
git commit -m "modified code"
git push originbit master

create repo on github
Open Sourcefree desktop app
copy the repo url
then click repo icon
then click on repo icon to add
then push on Sourcefree